Hidden Layer Descent Function Only Working Sometimes
I'm taking an AI class and we're using hidden layers to write a descent function to predict XOR gates in Python. For this assignment specifically it only needs to have 1 hidden layer of 3 hidden nodes. For some reason my code has only been working sometimes. Probably about 20% of the time after training it will be able to predict the outputs of (1, 1) as 0. (1, 0) as 1, (0, 1) as 1 and (0, 0) as 0. The other 80% of the time it will output 0.5 for all of them, which is about the worst possible output. I've tried adjusting everything such as the range for the random selection of coefficients, the learning rate and the iterations but nothings fixed the problem. I've checked my code tons of times and rewritten it a few times just to try to make it work but nothing has. Both my professor and classmates have checked it and can't find the problem, but I need to figure this out as it's pretty important for me to have this code working to pass the class. If anyone can find the issue with my code and help me fix it that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
import math


def hiddenDescentFunction(X, Y, iterations, learningRate):
    hCoef = [] #hidden layer coefficients
    oCoef = [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)] #output layer coefficients. oCoef[0] is bias
    for i in range(3): #initializes coefficients for each node in the hidden layer.
        tempArr = [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)]
        
        hCoef.append(tempArr)

    print(hCoef)
    print(oCoef)
    


    for i in range(iterations):
        for j in range(len(X)):
            output = predict(hCoef, oCoef, X[j])
            error =  (output[3] - Y[j])
            dError = (error * sigDir(output[3]))
            dh1 = (dError * oCoef[1] * sigDir(output[0]))
            dh2 = (dError * oCoef[2] * sigDir(output[1]))
            dh3 = (dError * oCoef[3] * sigDir(output[2]))
            oCoef = outAdjust(oCoef, learningRate, dError, output[0], output[1], output[2])
            hCoef = hidAdjust(hCoef, learningRate, X, j, dh1, dh2, dh3)
            

    #I need both the hidden and the output coefficients returned so I combine them into 1 array  
    outPutCof = hCoef 
    outPutCof.append(oCoef)
    return outPutCof

def outAdjust(oCoef, learningRate, dError, h1, h2, h3):
    oCoef[1] -= (learningRate * h1 * dError)
    oCoef[2] -= (learningRate * h2 * dError)
    oCoef[3] -= (learningRate * h3 * dError)
    oCoef[0] -= (learningRate * dError)
    return oCoef

def hidAdjust(hCoef, learningRate, X, j, dh1, dh2, dh3): 
    hCoef[0][1] -= (learningRate * X[j][1] * dh1)
    hCoef[0][2] -= (learningRate * X[j][2] * dh1)
    hCoef[0][0] -= (learningRate * dh1)
    hCoef[1][1] -= (learningRate * X[j][1] * dh2)
    hCoef[1][2] -= (learningRate * X[j][2] * dh2)
    hCoef[1][0] -= (learningRate * dh2)
    hCoef[2][1] -= (learningRate * X[j][1] * dh3)
    hCoef[2][2] -= (learningRate * X[j][2] * dh3)
    hCoef[2][0] -= (learningRate * dh3)
    return hCoef

    




def sigDir(X): #find sigmoid derivative
    sig = sigma(X)
    return (sig * (1 - sig))


#There are 4 things I need from the predict function, so I added them all into 1 array so I can return all of them 

def predict(hCoef, oCoef, X): #INPUT LIST FOR X, JUST THE NEEDED ROW. Example call: predict(hCoef, oCoef, X[1]) for the input X to = [1, 0]
    
    s1 = hCoef[0][1] * X[1] + hCoef[0][2] * X[2] + hCoef[0][0]
    
    s2 = hCoef[1][1] * X[1] + hCoef[1][2] * X[2] + hCoef[1][0]
    
    s3 = hCoef[2][1] * X[1] + hCoef[2][2] * X[2] + hCoef[2][0]
    

    output = [sigma(s1), sigma(s2), sigma(s3)] #h1 = output[0] h2 = output[1] h3 = output[2]

    sOut = output[0] * oCoef[1] + output[1] * oCoef[2] + output[2] * oCoef[3] + oCoef[0]
    output.append(sigma(sOut)) #prediction = output[3]
    return output

def sigma(input): #find sigmoid
    return (1/(1+math.exp(-(input))))



X = [ #X value. First column is coefficients
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0]
]



YXor = [0, 1, 1, 0]

def printArr(array):
    for row in array:
        for element in row:
            print(element, end=" ")  
        print("\n")

    print()

cof = hiddenDescentFunction(X, YXor, 100000, 0.1)
printArr(cof)

#for the predice function I need the output coefficients and hidden coefficients to be seperate so I create the output coefficients by initializing the hidden coefficients to all the coefficients and then popping the last row to the output coefficients

hArray = cof

oArray = hArray.pop(3)



prediction1 = predict(hArray, oArray, X[0])
prediction2 = predict(hArray, oArray, X[1])
prediction3 = predict(hArray, oArray, X[2])
prediction4 = predict(hArray, oArray, X[3])

print(prediction1[3], "\n", prediction2[3], "\n", prediction3[3], "\n", prediction4[3])



I've checked all the indexes of the arrays, the math for the adjustments, and I've rewritten the code a couple of times.
